# How can $r$ be negative when dealing with polar coordinates?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

If by definition $r=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, then why do we allow $r$ to be negative? Relatedly, I do not understand the last section of this [conversation](http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/discussions/PolarCoordinates/) discussing points being represented by multiple $\theta$:

> Student: So a single point could have many different values?
>
> Mentor: Correct! The values for $r$ can be given as positive and negative values and $\theta$ can be given not only in positive and negative values, but also as any value $\theta$ + any multiple of $2\pi$. So, unlike the Cartesian system where each point has a unique set of coordinates, in the polar system any point can have an infinite number of coordinates!
>
> Student: That means that the point given as $(2,\pi/4)$ could also be given as $(2,-7\pi/4)$ or $(2, 9\pi/4)$ or $(-2,5\pi/4)$!
>
> Mentor: Exactly. Try plotting those points using the Polar Coordinates activity and verify they are the same point!

This part in particular is confusing to me:

> $\theta$ can be given not only in positive and negative values, but also as
> any value $\theta$ + any multiple of 2π.

So if $\theta=5\pi/3$ then it would also equal $5\pi/3 + \pi$? I'm pretty confused on polar coordinates; they seem so inferior to traditional Cartesian when not dealing with imaginary numbers. Could someone clarify this redundancy in polar coordinates?

Comment: Polar coordinates in imaginary numbers are similer to those of trigonometry functions. As $\sin(x) = \sin(x+2k\pi)$. Which means that a point can have infinte number of values. I dont exactly understand your confusion.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, a point with polar coordinates $r,\theta$ has position:
$$x = r\cos \theta$$
$$y = r\sin \theta$$

Inverting this equation gives you many solutions, as you mentioned. Specifically for $r$, you can square both equations and add them up to get:
$$x^2 = r^2 \cos^2 \theta$$
$$y^2 = r^2 \sin^2 \theta$$
$$x^2+y^2 = r^2(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta) = r^2$$
From this, you can determine that $r$ can be either of the following:
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\quad -\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
Which one is true? If we know that $\cos \theta <0$, but $x>0$, then we must take $r=-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for the equation to "work out". If the converse is true, we must take the positive value.

In actual usage though, most people prefer to stick with positive $r$, and just change the angle accordingly. Thus instead of using $r=-1, \theta =-\pi$, people commonly just use $r=1, \theta =0$. This means that people just use $r=+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$,and then choose $\theta$ accordingly.

Comment: So if I had the point (2.5,5pi/3)  another answer could be (2.5,2pi/3)?

Comment: or would it be (-2.5,2pi/3)?

Comment: Option 2. Plot it out and see!

Comment: I think "actual usage" is context-dependent. If we're given Cartesian coordinates of a point in the plane and are asked for its polar coordinates, we'll generally pick a positive $r$ and a value of $\theta$ from a preferred interval of values such as $(-\pi,\pi].$ But if we are asked about the graph of $r = 2 \cos\theta,$ we will likely consider all real values of $\theta$, some of which result in negative values of $r.$